# tmux exit quickly and kill session

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

I have a few `tmuxinator` projects. When running one in `tmux` I would like to be able to exit it quickly (e.g. one key combination) and kill the session so that next time I open the project it starts in the same state. Detaching doesn't work as it doesn't reset the state.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `bind k kill-session` to `.tmux.conf`. And then you can exit and kill the session with `PREFIX k`.